# DoCmd.Sendobject not working in new outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I reported this to Microsoft also, but recently I checked the "try new outlook" box in my Outlook 365 and I've been using it successfully the last week or so. Yesterday I started working on developing a MS Access database with the Docmd.SendObject method of an access report in pdf format linked to a button on the form. When I click on the button, it seems to work successfully. My message box pops up, and then Outlook opens with the pdf attached to the e-mail message. I addressed it to myself for testing and clicked send, multiple times! It did not show in my sent folder and I never received it in my inbox. This morning I went ahead and unchecked the "try new outlook" box to open the classic outlook and within minutes I had all the messages I sent yesterday in both my inbox and sent folders with today's date. It seems that the method is opening classic outlook to send the message, but it wasn't going through successfully because I wasn't logged onto it long enough. Did I miss something new in Access?  I know it's continually changing. I run 64 bit office on my PC. I sincerely hope it works properly when everyone switches over permanently because I use this method in more than one database. My code is:

```
'Message to user
MsgBox "The form will attach to an email in outlook. This may take a moment, please be patient.", vbInformation, "E-Mail Method"
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
DoCmd.SendObject acReport, "RPT_NAME", "PDFFormat(*.pdf)", "", , , "Report Name # " & Me.PrimaryKey, _
"The attached file is the filled-out form. Please open it to review the data.", True
```

Comment: Bad news: https://www.accessforever.org/post/the-new-outlook-and-access-vba  (for many of us here...)